# Need help to retrieve rows from Data extension using Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, allrows

Can someone advise on how to retrieve Rows from a Data Extension using RestAPI?

Comment: You cannot use REST API to retrieve DE rows. You can use SOAP or Fuel SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible using the REST-API. To retrieve data extension rows, you need to use the SOAP-API.

**An example SOAP-Envelope would look like this:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Example DE]</ObjectType>
                <Properties>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Properties>
                <Properties>CUSTOMER_ID</Properties>
                <Properties>FIRST_NAME</Properties>
                <Properties>SITE_GROUP</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This would filter the results for email address *acruz@example.com*. To retrieve all rows, just remove the filter.

**Documentation articles:**

- [SOAP Web Service Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm)
- [Retrieve Data from a Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)

Comment: Does this feature available in future in RestAPI as we are using all other calls with RestAPI?

Comment: All the new features of Marketing Cloud are available only via the REST-API and I guess the features of the SOAP-API will slowly be migrated to the REST-API. However this is just a guess and no official statement of Salesforce and therefore there is no estimated time of arrival of these features at the moment.

Comment: any update on this? @MarkusSlabina